# Firebase Bill for 10k monthly active users

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I launched a social network app 1 month ago. It has around 10k monthly active users.

Image sizes are between 50kb and 200kb.

This is my current bill:

[image: Firebase Bill]

What are Non-Firebase services? Is it cloud vision, map sdk, extensions…?

Also, you can check that firebase cloud storage cost is 99% bandwidth:

[image: Storage Bandwidth]
[image]

Is it normal to pay 140$ per month for 10k users? My app has around 400 new users each day. Currently, **each week**, users upload around **3,500 photos** to the storage and fetch around **3 million photos** (posts for the feed, avatars, chat images...).

I'm getting a bit frustrated, as the app is pretty much trending on the app store, and I have no plans to monetize it until I build a solid user base.

Any advice? What can I do to reduce costs?

Comment: Cloud Storage has a high price for data transfer, as you said in your post, 3M images are being downloaded daily. Do you compress these images in any way when inserting into your storage?

Comment: @GabrielNexT not daily, weekly. I compress them using Expo Image Manipulator and Sharp. But, in order to avoid losing quiality, the resulted files are around 150kb. Also, I generate thumbnails and implement progressive image loading in the frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-Firebase services are charges related to non-Firebase GCP services. From this help-center page on :

> Costs for non-Firebase services can include any usage of services like the following:
>
> - Google APIs that are not Firebase-specific APIs
> - Project integrations like BigQuery
> - Compute Engine resources like Cloud Functions

You can find a breakdown of the non-firebase services cost in the [Google Cloud console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard). Since you already mention [Cloud Vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/pricing#prices) and [Google Maps](https://mapsplatform.google.com/pricing/), I recommend looking for those as the cost for those can indeed add up if you call them for each of your users.

There is no magic bullet to reducing the cost here. You will either have to use the APIs less frequently, use them on smaller amounts of data (e.g. like storing smaller images in Cloud Storage), or look for a cheaper/free service that offers the same functionality you need.

Comment: Thank you very much Frank. Will explore the different possibilities to reduce costs.